# Radeon HD 6630M

Tags: drivers, graphics, opengl

I have a "Lenovo ThinkPad Edge E520"

This is my GPU: ["Radeon HD 6630M"](http://www.game-debate.com/hardware/?gid=492&graphics=Radeon%20HD%206630M)

Running:

```
obs
```

Gives:

```
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale/en-US.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/locale.ini
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Default.qss
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/themes/Default.qss
Attempted path: share/obs/obs-studio/license/gplv2.txt
Attempted path: /usr/share/obs/obs-studio/license/gplv2.txt
info: OBS 0.10.0 (linux)
info: Processor: 4 logical cores
info: Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2350M CPU @ 2.30GHz
info: Physical Memory: 3863MB Total
info: Kernel Version: Linux 3.16.0-37-generic
info: Distribution: "Ubuntu" "14.04"
info: audio settings reset:
    samples per sec: 44100
    speakers:        2
    buffering (ms):  1000

info: X and Y: 902 489
Backbuffers: 2
Color Format: 3
ZStencil Format: 0
Adapter: 0

error: Failed to create OpenGL context.
error: Failed to create context!
*** Error in `obs': double free or corruption (out): 0x0000000001d00260 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I need to run `Open Broadcaster Software`.

```
 lspci | grep "VGA"
 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor
 Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

Ubuntu is not detecting my Graphic card

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
```

Comment: Please avoid Hi / Thanks taglines, and lots of bold if offputting.

Comment: Install the proprietary fglrx driver. This should enable a more recent OpenGL version...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Comment: THX but nothing work till now

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a proprietary video driver to extend features of your graphical card. You can do it by running

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

And reboot.

Due to a bug in fglrx-installer package the driver may not install. To fix it now you can go to System Settings -> Software & Updates -> Updates and click on proposed repository.

Then do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Then it is highly recommended to click proposed off before you install any of other updates.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                  xorg-video-abi-15
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: It looks like you have a non-standard installation. Please add information on what Ubuntu version is installed, what kernel version, etc.

Comment: Is in my post up [firt repor].info: Kernel Version: Linux 3.16.0-37-generic
info: Distribution: "Ubuntu" "14.04"

Comment: It is a bug. Fix is committed, but not released yet. I will update my answer.

Comment: I've click pre-released updates (trusty-proposed) ,copyed the comands and reboot. Nothing has been solvd